# How to add tag after base url in cms page in magento?

Tags: php, html, magento

In my cms page im writing url for a tag is

```
<a class="blue-btn" title="Personalize Now" href="{{store url="personalizer?pid=custom"}}">Personalize Now</a>
```

I want to get link like below

> http://localhost/appcustomizer-pdt-003/index.php/personalizer?pid=custom

I got url upto this - http://localhost/appcustomizer-pdt-003/index.php

But i dont know how to get -

> personalizer?pid=custom

Comment: (http://localhost/appcustomizer-pdt-003/index.php/%7B%7Bbase%20url='personalizer?pid=custom%27}} )   I got output like this

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for your requirement

```
<a class="blue-btn" title="Personalize Now" href="{{store url="personalizer"}}?pid=custom">Personalize Now</a>
```